# History of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

I have been trying to understand what is the meaning of [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), but to my mind it has been obscured behind complicated formulas without much explaination. I presume finding the history could be of use in understanding.

[The formulas](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-021-10072-y) I found are: $\frac{x}{1-e^{-x}} = \frac{x}{2}(\coth{\frac{x}{2}} + 1) = \sum^\infty_{k=0}{\frac{B_k x^k}{k!}}$

[One answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1222496/1204542) in math stack exchange said:

> It is a analytical continuation of the sum of the infinite series $\frac{1}{n^s}$, where the real part of the sum converges.

Is this true? I mean, $\frac{x}{1-e^x}$ does resemble $\frac{1}{1-x}$, but where do Bernoulli numbers come in here?

Comment: @Mauricio Yup, when I wrote it I missed the $\frac{x}{2}$ factor, now I edited it in, thanks!

Comment: What's the question here? If you're asking about the MSE answer, then your question belongs to MSE rather than HSMSE (and my answer would be: the linked answer is weird and misleading at best).

Comment: If you're asking for references on the history of Bernoulli numbers, you can just start with the Wikipedia page you linked to. There's a section "history" with a number of sources. I can also recommend [a nice essay by James Propp](https://mathenchant.wordpress.com/2022/09/17/what-lovelace-did-from-bombelli-to-bernoulli-to-babbage/).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Alright, sorry for the ambiguity of the question, I guess what I wanted was the easiest problem solved, which used Bernoulli numbers, I assumed it to be the problem which historically introduced them. The wikipedia and essay were useful! After some thought I now understand that the Bernoulli numbers are the coefficients for a sum of natural numbers to a power formula. Now I have a question on how he calculated the Bernoulli numbers, where those formulas for calculating them came from, but I suppose that this is a question for math stack exchange.

Comment: @Gustamons As Wikipedia says, the formulas appear in the posthumously published *Ars Conjectandi* (1713), dealing with permutations and combinations. Specifically in chapter 3 "De Combinationibus secundum singulos exponentes seorsim; ubi de Numeris Figuratis eorumque proprietatibus agitur" (Of the Combinations according to the individual exponents separately; where Figured Numbers and their properties are discussed), pp. 86-99. The *Summae Potestatum* are on [p. 97](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ars_Conjectandi/9M4dV_H9r8QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%20potestatum&pg=RA1-PA97&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @Gustamons An English translation of the complete *Ars Conjectandi* is available: Jacob Bernoulli. *The Art of Conjecturing, together with Letter to a Friend on Sets in Court Tennis.* Translated by, Edith Dudley Sylla. xx + 430 pp., illus., tables, bibl., index. Baltimore: Johns Hopkins University Press, 2006.

Comment: For history see [Kitagawa, The Origin of the Bernoulli Numbers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00283-021-10072-y), but historical firsts are rarely the simplest or most illuminating. On the relation to the zeta-function see [Shurman's notes, pp. 6-9](https://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/bernoulli.pdf), it comes out from representing coefficients in the power series for cotangent in two different ways. One uses Euler's formula that relates cotangent to the exponential function and Bernoulli numbers, and the other uses summation over its poles and geometric series to get zeta.